# ADDED_TO_STAGE function never called

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this class which should take a button from stage (**xBtn**).

```
package com.stx.utils {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class STXbutonx extends MovieClip {

        private var xBtn  : MovieClip;

        public function STXbutonx() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);           
        }

        private function init(e:Event=null) : void {
            trace("int!"); //this is never called
            xBtn = stage.getChildByName('ics') as MovieClip;
            xBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onX);
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function onX(e:MouseEvent) : void {
            trace("x Clicked!");
        }
    }
}
```

and in Document class I called like this :

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.stx.utils.*;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    var xx : STXbutonx;

    public function Main() {    
        xx = new STXbutonx();
    }
}
```

**Why my init function is never called?** 

 **Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you never add it to the stage.

Change your Document class to

```
public function Main() {    
    xx = new STXbutonx();
    addChild(xx);
}
```

Main holds the reference to the stage, adding a child to Main will add the child to the stage. Thus the event listener in STXbutonx will fire.

---

> xBtn = stage.getChildByName('ics') as MovieClip; // now I have acces of undefined property stage...

You don't have access to the stage because STXButon is not on the stage, it is not an DisplayObject. To get around this, do this:

package com.stx.utils {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;

public class STXbutonx{

    private var xBtn  : MovieClip;
    private var stage : Stage;

    public function STXbutonx(stage:Stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
        init();           
    }

    private function init() : void {
        trace("int!");
        xBtn = stage.getChildByName('ics') as MovieClip;
        xBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onX);
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function onX(e:MouseEvent) : void {
        trace("x Clicked!");
    }
}
```

}

And of course

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.stx.utils.*;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

var xx : STXbutonx;

public function Main() {    
    xx = new STXbutonx(stage);
}
```

}

Comment: but my 'ics' button is on the stage added manually, I just want to acces it from my class

Comment: You ask why the init function of STXbutonx is not called, the answer is that you never add STXbutonx to the stage. Your 'ics' button has nothing to do with this and is completely seperate from this question.

Comment: it is necessary to extend Movieclip in STXbuttonx class? because I don't want that class to be the class of 'ics' button. I want to be a class which acces some objects from stage and add them some functionality like mouse click... it is possible?

Comment: yes you are right about init function. I will accept yout answer. But give me an advice about what I want to make, if you want. Thanks

Comment: Nope, STXButonx does not have to extend any Class. But then you'll also have to remove your eventlistener, because an Object of the Class STXButonx will never be added to the stage. Instead of adding the event listener, call the init function directly in the constructor.

Comment: ok. And then how can I acces that button if I will not have any more stage object...?? :-|

Comment: The class STXButonx has a reference to the object on your stage. Your document has the reference to the Object of STXButonx. If you make your `xBtn` variable in STXButonx public instead of private, you'll have access to the Movieclip and can do stuff with it. Alternatively, you write functions in STXButonx that manipulate `xbtn` and make those functions available to the document class.

Comment: xBtn = stage.getChildByName('ics') as MovieClip; // now I have acces of undefined property stage...

Comment: Well, How is STXButonx supposed to have access to the stage if it isn't on it? Check out my edit.